# Trying to create API instance in API manager in Mule 4 using Azure Pipeline?

Tags: maven, azure-pipelines, mulesoft

I am trying to deploy end to end deployment of Mule app in Anypoint platform ( include create API manager and deploy in runtime manager). I am using maven as build tool.
I am able to deploy the app in Runtime manager but the creation of API manager is not happening so have to create it manually.

is there any command to create API instance from exchange?
I am using below command to achieve it but unfortunately its not working :
'clean package -Du=$(uname) -Dp=$(pass) -DorgId=$(org.id) -Dv=$(Build.BuildNumber) -DenvId=$(environment) -DdeploymentType=cloudhub -Dpackaging=pom -DassetId=$(app.name) -Dpolicy=$(policy1)'

Comment: Did the [CLI for API Manager](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-cli/4.x/api-mgr) as suggested by Harshank help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can not manage APIs in API Manager using the mule maven plugin. However, you can use [anypoint-cli](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-cli/4.x/) to do so. There are many options commands to [manage API Manager using the CLI tool](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-cli/4.x/api-mgr). You will probably need to use the [promote command](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-cli/4.x/api-mgr#api-mgr-api-promote) but you can playaround and see what you suits your requirement the most